# Set value for object field by reflection in java

Tags: java, reflection

First, I have an object like that:

```
public class Entity {
    public int data1;
    public String data2;
    public float data3;
    public SubEntity data4;
}

public class SubEntity{
    public int id;
    public SubEntity(int id){
      tis.id = id;
    }
}
```

And a HashMap:

```
  HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  map.put("data1", 1);
  map.put("data2", "name");
  map.put("data3", 1.7);
  map.put("data4", new SubEntity(11));
```

I need the right way to set value for all field of entity dynamic by use reflect from hashmap. Something like this:

```
    for (Field f : entity.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
       String name = f.getName();
       Object obj = map.get("name");
       // Need set value field base on its name and type. 

}
```

How can I achieve that? Assume I have many sub classes in entity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to go the reflection route, then why not use [Field.set(Object, Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) and its more type-safe siblings (see doc)

```
f.set(myEntity, obj);
```

Note. You may need to [make the field accessibl](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28boolean%29)e first if it's private/protected.

However if you can I would perhaps delegate to the object and it could populate itself via the map e.g.

```
myEntity.populateFromMap(myMap);
```

and do the hard(ish) work within your class.